# Inequality involving integral of $\Gamma(x)$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

The graph of $\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}$ is somewhat bell-shaped. I think the proof of the following requires an understanding of the integral of this function that I can't glean from either *Mathematica* or the usual assortment of Wiki entries. Can one show that

> $$e^e< \int_{-1^+}^{10}\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx~~~?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Numerical evaluation of the integral is $15.17923074$.

Comment: Let me double check.

Comment: Maybe you can use the infinite product of the gamma function. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html , equation (2).

Comment: @daniel: It holds. I made a calculation mistake. Now you need to prove it.

Comment: The limit $10$ seems arbitrary to me. What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: @YuriyS:  The limit appears arbitrary. This probably came up in some numerical context and I was interested in bounding the integral. It was posted two years ago and I do not recall the context.

Comment: @daniel, I see, thanks. I always forget to look at the date of the OP